# Multiple picker views: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to create a view controller with multiple pickerviews using the following code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class DormViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var dormName: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var entryway: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var roomNumber: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!

    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    let dorms = ["Adams", "Apley", "Cabot", "Canaday", "Currier", "DeWolfe 10", "Dewolfe 20", "Dunster", "Eliot", "Fairfax", "Grays", "Greenough", "Hollis", "Holworthy", "Hurlbut", "Inn at Harvard", "Kirkland", "Leverett Towers", "Leverett McKinlock Hall", "Lionel", "Lowell", "Massachusetts Hall", "Mather Lowrise", "Mather Tower", "Matthews", "Mower", "New Quincy", "Pennypacker", "Pforzheimer", "Pforzheimer Jordan North", "Pforzheimer Jordan South", "Stone Hall", "Stoughton", "Straus", "Thayer", "Weld", "Wigglesworth", "Winthrop" ]

    let entrances = ["N/A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

    let rooms = ["N/A", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        dormName = UIPickerView()
        entryway = UIPickerView()
        roomNumber = UIPickerView()

        dormName.delegate = self
        dormName.dataSource = self
        entryway.delegate = self
        entryway.dataSource = self
        roomNumber.delegate = self
        roomNumber.dataSource = self


        dormName.tag = 0
        entryway.tag = 1
        roomNumber.tag = 2

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return dorms[row]
        }
        else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
            return entrances[row]
        }
        else {
            return rooms[row]
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return dorms.count
        }
        else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
            return entrances.count
        }
        else {
            return rooms.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

        if let user = user {
            let uid = user.uid
            var entry = entrances[row]
            var num = rooms[row]

            if entrances[row] == "N/A" {
                entry = ""
            }

            if rooms[row] == "N/A" {
                num = ""
            }

            self.ref.child("Dorms").child(uid).setValue(["Location": dorms[row] + " " + entry + "-" + num ])
        }
        else {
            print("error")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "tohomepage", sender: self)
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

In my `viewDidLoad()` function, when I make the call:

```
dormName.delegate = self
```

I've tried deleting the delegate and dataSource calls, and the same error still happens. I also tried deleting the tags and referencing the picker views by their names, as in:

```
pickerview == "dormName"
```

But then I get an **`index out of range`** error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you building your UI? It looks like you've created it with Storyboards but then you override those properties in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Your `viewDidLoad` makes no sense. You have outlets. This implies you are using a storyboard. Then why do you create empty picker views and set their delegates and data sources in code? Hook everything up in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

when you drag UIPickerView from xib or storyboad you don't need call some init :

```
dormName = UIPickerView()
entryway = UIPickerView()
roomNumber = UIPickerView()
```

delete it , and try again

Comment: I deleted those three lines but I'm still getting the same error on the line:    var entry = entrances[row]...the error is that index is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

In your `didSelectRow` you do not check for the picker instance anymore and just access the data of all arrays by the same `row` index. This will cause an *index out of range* error as soon as you pick an item with an index that goes beyond the smallest array length (in this case, `entrances`).

Also, looks like you have your tags/indices wrong. E.g. you set the `tag` of `dormName` to 0, but in your code you access the dorm data when the `tag` equals 1 (which in fact refers to the `entryway` picker).